# Execute functions based on object given as property value

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an object containing property values as function names. This is my object `obj`:

```
var obj = {
    beforeCalc: beforeCalc,
    calcEcn: calcEcn
};

function beforeCalc() {
    console.log("beforeCalcMethodExecuted");
}

function calcEcn() {
    console.log("calcEcnMethodExecuted");
}
```

Running the objects property values like this.

```
function runMethodsFromObj() {
    for (var i in obj) {
    console.log(i); // beforeCalc, calcEcn
    console.log(i()); //i is not defined 
  }
}
runMethodsFromObj();
```

Why is it returning `undefined`?

Comment: Try `obj[i]()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `for-in` loop gives you the `keys` of the object and `not their value`

```js
var obj = {
    beforeCalc: beforeCalc,
    calcEcn: calcEcn
};
function beforeCalc() {
    console.log("beforeCalcMethodExecuted");
}
function calcEcn() {
    console.log("calcEcnMethodExecuted");
}

function runMethodsFromObj() {
  for (var i in obj) {
    console.log(i); // beforeCalc, calcEcn
    console.log(typeof i); // string
    obj[i](); // Executes the stored function 
  }
}
runMethodsFromObj();
```